# Modified NIM game

Tags: contest-math, game-theory

There are two rock piles. The first pile contains N rocks, and the second one contains M rocks, where
*($0  ≤  N, M  ≤  10^{9}$)* .
First and second players take turns to play the game, In each turn, a player can choose to take one rock from a single pile, or take one rock from both piles. The player who cannot make any move, loses the game.

So I don't know how to modify the xor equation to work with this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**  Losing positions are $(N,M)$ such that $N$ and $M$ are both even.

Comment: Sorry I don't really get what you meant. So if both(N, M) are even, who gonna lose, the first or the second one?

Comment: The term *losing positions* means that, if you encounter them, you have no winning strategies.  So, when $N$ and $M$ are both even, the first player loses (because he will have to play the position $(N,M)$).